# dplyr::filter() based on dplyr::lag() without losing first values

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, lead

When I filter a dataset based on a lag() function, I lose the first row in each group (because those rows have no lag value). How can I avoid this so that I keep the first rows despite their not having any lag value?

```
ds <- 
  structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 21.4, 18.7, 14.3, 16.4), cyl = c(6, 
  6, 6, 8, 8, 8), hp = c(110, 110, 110, 175, 245, 180)), class = c("tbl_df", 
  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("mpg", 
  "cyl", "hp"))

# example of filter based on lag that drops first rows
ds %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  arrange(-mpg) %>% 
  filter(hp <= lag(hp))
```

Comment: `lag(hp,default = hp[1])`?

Comment: @joran, manipulating the default argument in this way is a good solution, and can be updated to "filter(hp > lag(hp, default = hp[1] - 1))" in cases where equivalence is insufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `filter(hp <= lag(hp))` excludes rows where `lag(hp)` is `NA`. You can instead filter for *either* that inequality *or* for `lag(hp)`, as is the case for those top rows of each group.

I included `prev = lag(hp)` to make a standalone variable for the lags, just for clarity & debugging.

```
library(tidyverse)

ds %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    arrange(-mpg) %>%
    mutate(prev = lag(hp)) %>%
    filter(hp <= prev | is.na(prev))
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [2]
    mpg   cyl    hp  prev
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21.4    6.  110.   NA 
2  21.0    6.  110.  110.
3  21.0    6.  110.  110.
4  18.7    8.  175.   NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `OP` intends to use `<=` (less than or equal to) with previous value, hence using `lag` with `default = +Inf` will be sufficient.

Also, there is no need to have separate `arrange` call in `dplyr` chain as `lag` provides option to select `order_by`.

Hence, solution can be written as:

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  filter(hp <= lag(hp, default = +Inf, order_by = -mpg))

#Below result is in origianl order of the data.frame though lag was calculated 
#in ordered value of mpg
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups: cyl [2]
#     mpg   cyl    hp
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21.0  6.00   110
# 2  21.0  6.00   110
# 3  21.4  6.00   110
# 4  18.7  8.00   175
```